# using angular, express and mongoDB: How to format date in input element without breaking NgModel?

Tags: html, angular, mongodb, express

I have an deadlineDate (Date format) property in my mongoDB. In my component.html I have an input field where I want the user to be able to change the deadlineDate.

when opening the component.html the full date is shown in the input textfield

```
<label>project deadline:
    <input [(ngModel)]="project.deadlineDate" 
        placeholder="{{project.deadlineDate | date }}" 
        type="text"  
        onfocus="(this.type='date')" 
        onblur="(this.type='text')" />
 </label>
```

returns on opening html: 2019-02-20T00:00:00.000Z in my input field. I want it to return 20-02-2019

any ideas on how I can format this? Suggestions on how to make this more userfriendly/ -usable/ -readable are also welcome ofcourse.-

component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getProject();
  };

 getProject(): void {
        const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.projectService.getProject(id)
          .subscribe(project => this.project = project);
      };
```

service.ts

```
getProject(id: string): Observable<Project> {
  const url = `${this.backendUrl}/project/${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Project>(url)
    .pipe(
      map(project => project[0]),
      tap(res => console.log(res)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Project>(`getProject id=${id}`))
    );
};
```

Comment: Your input is binding exactly like it should -- `.deadlineDate` is an date string so it displays it as such -- trying to override the `placeholder` will not work like you intend. I suggest using a datepicker library - Angular Material makes a good one https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api as does `ngx` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-datepicker-material

Comment: thanks, I'm trying material now. I've imported the following in app.module:   `  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule
  ],`  any ideas onhow my component ts and html should look? your help is very welcome

Comment: No problem -- and sure, please update your question with code you've tried, documentation you've referenced and the errors you're seeing.

Comment: I realize I have to learn material first.. thanks for the help!